# Dynamics CRM plugin

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, crm

I have dynamics CRM plugin which is stricted to org id
Developer is not available already for several years.
How i can change org id in new Dynamics CRM on premise so it will be the same as on original server?

Plugin cant be exported while it is managed solution

Answer (score 0):

using XrmToolBox, name tool **Plug-in Downloader** and export plugin and registration it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqjbP.jpg)